# find duplicates

Tags: objective-c

You are given an array of elements. Some/all of them are duplicates. Find them in 0(n) time and 0(1) space. Property of inputs - Number are in the range of 1..n where n is the limit of the array.

Comment: How can you even enumerate the duplicates in constant space?

Comment: what does this have to do with objective-c? it seems like any answer you come up with would work in pretty much any language

Comment: I was asked kind of the same question in an interview. First you have to put the elements in a hashtable (complexity O(n) ) and then find them in O(1).

Comment: @nacho, I'm pretty certain that even with a hash, the space requirement is O(n), not O(1). But, if you're confident you're right, that belongs in an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: @nacho4d ya u can do it using hashmap but look at the problem you have to do it in constant space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the O(1) storage is a limitation on additional memory, and not an indication that you can't modify the input array, then you can do it by sorting while iterating over the elements: move each misplaced element to its "correct" place - if it's already occupied by the correct number then print it as a duplicate, otherwise take the "incorrect" existing content and place it correctly before continuing the iteration.  This may in turn require correcting other elements to make space, but there's a stack of at most 1 and the total number of correction steps is limited to N, added to the N-step iteration you get 2N which is still O(N).

Comment: You need to flesh this out a little more, I think. It's close but I still can't see it as O(n). Assuming that you're iterating over the array element by element, what is the O(1) operating that will guarantee placement of the _chain_ of values? In other words, you can't just swap the two values `a[3] = 7` and `a[7] = 12` since now `a[3]` is 12 and you have to swap again.

Comment: i think you have to store the other value in some temporary variable.then continue with same approach.

Comment: @paxdiablo: as mentioned in my fleshless answer, the total of length of such correction chains must be <= N for the entire process: for example, if the chain of corrections involved with placing the first element required every element to be corrected, then the other elements are then in place and there's simply a confirmatory iteration left to do.  So, while it seems N^2 at casual glance, it's more like 2N once this is factored in....

Comment: Actually, that makes sense with your added comment (and in the original now that I've re-read it more closely), so I'll give you 1 for that.

Comment: @prp, feel free to implement the algorithm that Tony gave you. SO is _not_ a homework service.

Comment: @paxdiablo: my feelings exactly.  @prp: if you at least try yourself, you'll be able to come back here and ask for help with whatever bits aren't working, but it's not in the spirit of SO to just expect people to do stuff when you're not trying hard yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Since both the number of elements in the array *and* the range of the array are variable based on `n`, I don't believe you can do this. I *may* be wrong, personally I doubt it, but I've been wrong before :-)

> **EDIT:** And it looks like I may be wrong again :-) See Tony's answer, I believe he may have nailed it. I'll delete this answer once enough people agree with me, or it gets downvoted too much :-)

If the range was *fixed* (say, `1..m`), you could do it thus:

```
dim quant[1..m]
for i in 1..m:
    quant[m] = 0
for i in 1..size(array):
    quant[array[i]] = quant[array[i]] + 1
for i in 1..m:
    if quant[i] > 1:
        print "Duplicate value: " + i
```

This works since you can often trade off space against time in most algorithms. But, because the range also depends on the input value, the normal trade-off between space and time is not plausible.

Comment: again you are using extra space for finding duplicates.Even in your way of doing you can optimize, instead of using one entry in array for storing status of one element better use one bit for each element,that will be space optimization.

Comment: @prp, the extra storage is not dependent on the input value but a constant `m` - that's why it's O(1), since doubling `n` has no effect on storage requirements. But it's moot since the range in the question _is_ dependent on `n`.

Comment: your solution is dependent on m i guess try solving it with constant space without dependent on m.